# How do I tell perl to execute a piece of generated Perl code?

Tags: perl, ksh

I am trying to catch the string `cd /a/b/c` and do the following conversion
(as part of a larger Perl program).

If `cd /a/b/c` exists then convert `cd /a/b/c` → `chdir '/a/b/c'` and execute `chdir '/a/b/c'`

I can do the conversion; I can't tell `perl` to execute my command.

Comment: Can you please specify what you're catching *in general*?  An arbitrary shell command?  Then why use Perl to execute it?

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    if ( my ($path) = $line =~ m{^cd \s+ (/? (\w+) (?:/\w+)* )}x ) {
        warn "Path is $path\n";
        chdir $path
            or warn "Cannot chdir to '$path': $!";
    }
}

__DATA__
cd a
cd /a/b/c
cd /a
```

Output:

```
Path is a
Cannot chdir to 'a': No such file or directory at C:\Temp\k.pl line 8,  line 1.
Path is /a/b/c
Cannot chdir to '/a/b/c': No such file or directory at C:\Temp\k.pl line 8,  line 2.
Path is /a
Cannot chdir to '/a': No such file or directory at C:\Temp\k.pl line 8,  line 3.
```

Answer (score 2):

What you really want is a dispatch table. When you encounter a command, like `cd`, you look up an associated subroutine in the dispatch table where you map valid commands to the code that you want to run:

```
%dispatch = (
     cd => sub { chdir( $_[0] ) }, 
     ...
     );

while( <> )
     {
     my( $command, @args ) = split;
     if( exists $dispatch{ $command } )
          {
          $dispatch{ $command }->(@args);
          }
     }
```

I have several extended examples of this sort of thing in [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242). The nice bit about this is that you don't change the processing loop when you have new commands, and you only handle the commands you intend to handle. Furthermore, you can construct that dispatch table directly from configuration.

Answer (score 1):

if the directory you want to find is known beforehand.

```
$str = "blah blah cd /a/b/c blah";
if ( $str =~ /cd \/a\/b\/c/ ){
  print "found\n";
  chdir("/a/b/c");
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about something like this:

$str = "cd /a/b/c";

@dir = split /\s/ , $str;
$dir[1] = "chdir";
$new_dir = join ($" , @dir );

eval $new_dir;


SO, why can't I cd/eval/exec the $new_dir command and go there?